# Intrusion Detection with data analysis(with R)

Tags: r, data-visualization, dataset

I should do analysis about "Intrusion Detector Learning" in data Science course. Software to detect network intrusions protects a computer network from unauthorized users, including perhaps insiders. The intrusion detector learning task is to build a predictive model, i.e., a classifier, capable of distinguishing between "bad" connections, called intrusions or attacks, and normal connections.

A connection is a sequence of TCP packets starting and ending at some well-defined times, between which data flows to and from a source IP address to a target IP address under some well-defined protocol. Each connection is labeled as either normal, or as an attack, with exactly one specific attack type. Each connection record consists of about 100 bytes. Attacks fall into four main categories:

- DOS: denial-of-service, e.g. syn flood;
- R2L: unauthorized access from a remote machine, e.g. guessing password;
- U2R: unauthorized access to local superuser (root) privileges, e.g., various „buffer overflow“ attacks;
- probing: surveillance and other probing, e.g., port scanning.

My dataset has 42 features:

```
"duration","protocol_type","service","flag","src_bytes","dst_bytes","land",
"wrong_fragment","urgent","hot","num_failed_logins","logged_in","num_compromised",
"root_shell","su_attempted","num_root","num_file_creations","num_shells",
"num_access_files","num_outbound_cmds","is_host_login","is_guest_login",
"count","srv_count","serror_rate","rerror_rate","srv_serror_rate","rerror_rate",
"srv_rerror_rate","same_srv_rate","diff_srv_rate","srv_diff_host_rate",
"dst_host_srv_count","dst_host_same_srv_rate","dst_host_diff_srv_rate",
"dst_host_same_src_port_rate","dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate","dst_host_serror_rate",
"dst_host_srv_serror_rate","dst_host_rerror_rate","dst_host_srv_rerror_rate","connect_type"
```

My task has 2 steps:

1. Analyze the dataset to obtain helpful information about the data.
2. Based on your analysis, please build a ML model that classifies connections into different categories.

Can you please give me some advice how should I done step 1? I do not know which feature is more important. I made subsets of my dataset: normal,dos,r2l,u2r and probing. I build density plots based on connect_type. But don't any other idea base of which features (for x and y) should I build other plots.

P.S.: I am using R.

Comment: You may start out by a random forest algorithm. In R see randomForest package.

Comment: But how should I deal with step 1? I can not understand my features how can I use random forest before having any idea about how to deal with my data